# check number that are non-negative integer and not alphabet

Tags: python

i want to continue the loop for asking input(), i use "type(p) is not int" to check the alphabet number, but i get UnboundLocalError when i use "type(p) is not int"

```
def check(p):
    """
>>> get the value which is non-negative integer and not alphabet
    Checking if the input is negative or not.
    or repeat asking for input
    loop will terminate until positive integer
    """
    while p < 0 or type(p) is not int:
        p = float(input("Invaild response, please try again:"))
    return p

check("4")
check(4)
```

i want to continue the loop for asking input(), i use "type(p) is not int" to check the alphabet number, but i get UnboundLocalError when i use "type(p) is not int"

Comment: Please try to use correct upper case letters, e.g. in the beginning of your title, sentences or the word "I". This would be gentle to your readers.

Comment: Python doesn't know what `p` is at the while loop. It is only created on the next line. Perhaps you should try adding `p = -1` on the line before the loop.

Comment: replace `p` with `num` in your function body

Comment: `p` is not defined at the first iteration. Also the check for `type(p) is not int` is a bit useless as `p = float(...)` so it will ***always*** be true...

Comment: The argument `4` or `"4"` to the function is unused and does nothing…?!

Answer (score 0):

```py
def check(num):
    while type(num) is not int or num < 0:
        try:
            num = int(input("Invaild response, please try again:"))
        except ValueError:
            pass
    return num

      
check("4")
```

Outputs:

```py
print(check(-4))

#Output: Invaild response, please try again:

print(check(4.2))

#Output: Invaild response, please try again:

print(check("4"))

#Output: Invaild response, please try again:

print(check(4))

#Output: 4
```